# Convert custom Yolov4 .weight file to Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolov4

I have trained my custom object using Yolov4 and I have the following file :

```
yolov4-custom_best.weights
yolov4-custom.cfg
obj.names
```

'obj.names' has the names of the classes of the custom object.

In order to deploy my custom object detector to a web application I need the files in a tensorflow model format `(eg : object_detector.h5)`

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the model files in **.h5** format you have to save the model. To save the model you can use

```
# The '.h5' extension indicates that the model should be saved to HDF5.
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

You can also save the model by using `tf.keras.models.save_model()`

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model,filepath,save_format='h5')
```

For more details, please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model). Thank You!